# Android freezes Eclipse when running emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am using Eclipse Indigo with Android SDK and Eclipse plugin. 
Very often when I'm running the application and I click on the Logcat tab in Java o DDMS perspective it causes Eclipse to freeze. I have to restart Eclipse and restart application. Can you help me?

Comment: Hard to diagnose like that. Maybe try running eclipse from a shell and looking at the output?

Comment: This sounds more like an Eclipse IDE issue. Have you tried other versions of Eclipse to see if you have the same result?

Comment: I have reinstalled Eclipse Indigo, the problem is not resolved.